# ASP.NET DataSource with parameters for SQL IN clause

Tags: asp.net

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="DataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DbConnection %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DbConnection.ProviderName %>" 
    SelectCommand="select somefield from sometable where somefield in (?)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="" Name="SomeFiedValue" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

How (from my codebehind) do I allocate a list of values for the parameter in the above SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
protected void DataSource1_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Command.Parameters["SomeFieldValue"].Value = yourdata;
}
```

EDIT:

Based on your answers, please have a look at the following website. It explains one way to solve this problem with `DB2`.

http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1443561

Based on the comments on that page, a possible solution for your problem could be:

```
select somefield from sometable where somefield in 
(select ? from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1)
```

Comment: I got this working with a single value "someValue" but how do I get it working with a list "someValue1,someValue2"?

Comment: Could you please provide more information as to what it is you are looking to do so that the best possible solution can be provided to you.

Comment: I want to write an SQL like this `select somefield from sometable where somefield in ('val1','val2','val3')`, however the in clause could have any number of values.  On one call it might be 3 on another it might be 10.  That is why I want to use an in caluse with a varible as a parameter.

Comment: If your backend database is MySQL you can use the following function to complete the task: WHERE FIND_IN_SET(fieldname,multiplevalues) > 0.

Comment: `select ? from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1` I don't think that will work.  That table contain a single row.

Comment: If you have a look at the website provided they list an example similar to the one I posted that uses a union query. I thought that generally it would suit your needs.

Comment: It looks like they are using 2 separate fields for an `in` clause.  I just want a regular `in` clause.  This will not help me with my problem.  As far as I can tell, I can't solve this without manually constructing the SQL query in code as opposed to using an XML DataSource.